# Error parsing and setting cookies on Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently trying to parse my session cookies from python requests and sending them to my chrome extension. I'm facing some issues with more complicated cookies like this one:

[image: python cookies]

My python code looks like this:

```py
cookieStr = ''
            cookies = [
            {'name': c.name, 'value': c.value, 'domain': c.domain, 'path': c.path, 'url': ''} for c in cookiesGet]

            for cookie in cookies:
                if cookie['domain'][0] == ".":
                    cookie['url'] = cookie['domain'][1:]
                else:
                    cookie['url'] = cookie['domain']
                    cookie['url'] = "https://"+cookie['url']

                cookies = json.dumps(cookies)
                print(cookies)
                cookieStr = urllib.parse.quote(base64.b64encode(bytes(cookies, 'utf-8')).decode())
                if not cookieStr:
                    print('')
                url = urllib.parse.quote(base64.b64encode(bytes(redirectUrl, 'utf-8')).decode())
```

Facing issues on extension with this error:
[image: CHROME EXTENSION ERROR]

And of course extension JS code looks like this:

```
function setCookie(cookieName, cookieDomain, cookieUrl, cookieVal) {
    // console.log(cookieName,cookieDomain, cookieVal,cookieUrl);
    chrome.cookies.set({
        "name": cookieName,
        "domain": cookieDomain,
        "url": cookieUrl,
        "value": cookieVal
    }, function (cookie) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(cookie));
        console.log(chrome.extension.lastError);
        console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
    });
}

function parseCookie(cookie) {
    setCookie(cookie['name'], cookie['domain'], cookie['url'], cookie['value']);
}

function init() {
......
.....
var cookieStr = decodeURIComponent(url.searchParams.get("cookie"))//.replace(" ", "+");
cookieStr = atob(cookieStr);
console.log(cookieStr);
var cookies = JSON.parse(cookieStr);
var redirect = atob(url.searchParams.get("redirect").toString());

for (var cookie of cookies) {
   parseCookie(cookie)
}
```

Comment: Use devtools to set a breakpoint at that line and inspect the actual value of `cookieUrl`. It's probably not a valid URL.

Comment: Error handling response: TypeError: Error in invocation of cookies.set(object details, optional function callback): Error at parameter 'details': Missing required property 'url'.

Comment: Yeah, sorry posted wrong comment, I'm trying to use devtools by setting up breakpoints and logging important stuff